# A complete tutorial about Eclipse Branding , Making your own eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, branding

I want to make an eclipse like Flex Builder does, so all colors and controls will be defined by me.
I think this is known as Eclipse Branding. But I couldn't get the entire exact way of doing the eclipse branding in a larger prospect(how adobe did with Flex Builder or Google did with GWT)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the eclipse branding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007846/change-the-eclipse-branding)

Comment: actually the link suggested doesn't recommend the way to change the entire eclipse like Flex Builder and all ...

Answer (score 2):

Search for "Eclipse look&feel" and "Eclipse presentation factory".

And have a look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_Custom_Look_and_Feel

Answer (score 1):

There are two articles to branding eclipse (only before version 4).

First to branding a simple feature:

http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/brand-your-feature-and-be-part-of-about-eclipse/

Second to branding a rcp application:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html

( Additional it is important add to your MANIFEST.MF the line

Bundle-Localization: plugin

see here: [Externalizing strings in plugin.xml for Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644848/externalizing-strings-in-plugin-xml-for-eclipse-plugin) )